# Docusign. Not able to sign a doc with createRecipientView method url

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope. My flow is next:

- Obtaining OAuth token
- Creating envelope based on existing template
- Using createRecipientView method to get redirect url for the first signer(Later I'm taking the existing envelope id and creating redirect url for the second signer)

The problem:

It works as I expect if only signer's email address belongs to my docusign developer account. In other words if it is in the list of my docusign dev account users. Otherwise, with any random email address, I'm being redirected to the document page but I'm only able to view it and close, there's no start->sign->finish button(I'm not able to sign a doc).

One thing I've noticed is the wrong recipientId which is equal to zeros and dashes(normally it has a set of numbers and letters). I find it at a signing page -> other actions -> Session Information. It's hapenning when I'm being redirected as a user with any email(one that does not belong to docusign account). BUT, every signer receives an email notification with the same link to the document and If I go from that link, I can sign a document no matter what email address it is.

[Session information with the wrong recipientId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIJ3C.png)

My code:

```
const client = new docusign.ApiClient()
client.setBasePath('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi')
client.setOAuthBasePath('account-d.docusign.com')

const tokenResponse = await client.requestJWTUserToken(userId, integrationKey, ['impersonation', 'signature'], privateKey, 600)

client.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ` + tokenResponse.body.access_token)
const envelopesApi = await new docusign.EnvelopesApi(client)

const envelope = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, {
  envelopeDefinition: {
    templateId: templateId,
    status: 'sent',
    emailSubject: `Signing template ID: ${templateId}`,
    templateRoles: [
      { roleName: args.firstRole, name: args.firstSignerName, email: args.firstSignerEmail },
      { roleName: args.secondRole, name: args.secondSignerName, email: args.secondSignerEmail },
    ],
  }
})

const recipientView = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelope.envelopeId, {
  recipientViewRequest: {
    returnUrl: my local host,
    email: args.firstSignerEmail,
    userName: args.firstSignerName,
    authenticationMethod: 'none',
  },
})

return recipientView
```

Please, let me know If you know what I'm doing wrong.

I read docusign docs and thought I'm missing some permission, but so far can't figure out what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but based on your description, you haven't set up a clientUserId parameter for your recipients. Recipient Views are created for [embedded signers](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/) wherein you embed the signing session into your own application. As embedded recipients are a special class of recipients associated only with the sender's account, this could explain why your recipient view works for users already part of your account but does not work for anyone else.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. clientUserId is kinda confusing property for me. I'm reading the docs but still can't find where I get this id from or how I set it. Could you give me more details on that, please?

Comment: I got it. It's just a unique identifier for each individual signer. Adding that helped with my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yes! That's pretty much it. If you'd like to discuss the use cases for this further, I'd recommend opening a case with DocuSign Developer Support so that I or one of my colleagues can expand on this further.